# JSON Representation of a Backbone Model

Tags: ajax, json, backbone.js

Forking a json file using fetch method triggers error in my code. Seems the response from the server is not right. Into the details, for the ads model below

```
//Advertisement model
App.Tasks.Model.Ads = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "ads/ads.json",
    intialize: function () {

    },
    Next: function () {
        var ads = this.get("ads");
        return ads[Math.ceil(Math.random(0, ads.legth) * 10)];
    }
});
```

how should the server response be when calling `fetch()`. Right now it is as below

```
{ads: ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"]}
```

and doing this triggers the **error** callback

```
//Advertisement model
App.Tasks.Ads = new App.Tasks.Model.Ads();
App.Tasks.Ads.fetch({
    success: function (model, response) {
        console.log("Success", arguments);
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
        console.log("Error", arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: If it's the exact response from the server, ads should be wrapped in double quotes : `{"ads": ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"]}`

Comment: @nikoshr you know something? You have talent for the details. Put this into answer i will mark it so that other too can benefit

Comment: :) Glad it helped. Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server responds with an invalid JSON, the left part in a name/value pair must be a string, which means that `ads` should be wrapped in double quotes:

```
{"ads": ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"]}
```

For the complete reference, check http://www.json.org/